# Add quotes at the start and end of each line in a multiline cell

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Let's say I have a cell that contains:

```
alpha
beta
charlie
delta
```

Is there a way by formula or search/replace (probably using regex like find (.+) and replace with "$&") to make it like this?:

```
"alpha"
"beta"
"charlie"
"delta"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data (if the values per line **don't contain whitespace**), the following will work (tested with LibreOffice Calc 4.2):

- Search for `([:alnum:]+)`,
- replace with `"$1"` (with `Regular Expressions` enabled):

[image]